# Why does '\x01\x1A' (Start-of-Header and Substitute control characters) in a textfile line stop a for-loop prematurely?

Tags: python, for-loop, readlines, control-characters

I'm using *Python 2.7.15, Windows 7*

**Context**

I wrote a script to read and tokenize each line of a FileZilla log file (specifications [here](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Server_logs)) for the IP address of the host that initiated the connection to the FileZilla server. I'm having trouble parsing the `log text` field that follows the `>` character. The script I wrote uses the:

```
    with open('fz.log','r') as rh:
       for lineno, line in rh: 
          pass
```

construct to read each line. That for-loop stopped prematurely when it encountered a `log text` field that contained the `SOH` and `SUB` characters. I can't show you the log file since it contains sensitive information but the crux of the problem can be reproduced by reading a textfile that contains those characters on a line.

My goal is to extract the IP addresses (which I can do using `re.search()`) but before that happens, I have to remove those control characters. I do this by creating a copy of the log file where the lines containing those control characters are removed. There's probably a better way, but I'm more curious why the for-loop just stops after encountering the control characters.

**Reproducing the Issue**

I reproduced the problem with this code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fn = 'writetest.txt'
    fn2 = 'writetest_NoControlChars.txt'

    # Create the problematic textfile
    with open(fn, 'w') as wh: 
        wh.write("This line comes first!\n");
        wh.write("Blah\x01\x1A\n"); # Write Start-of-Header and Subsitute unicode character to line
        wh.write("This comes after!")

    # Try to read the file above, removing the SOH/SUB characters if encountered
    with open(fn, 'r') as rh:
        with open(fn2, 'w') as wh:
            for lineno, line in enumerate(rh):
                sline = line.translate(None,'\x01\x1A')
                wh.write(sline)
                print "Line #{}: {}".format(lineno, sline)
    print "Program executed."
```

**Output**

The code above creates 2 output files and produces the following in a console window:

```
Line #0: This line comes first!

Line #1: Blah
Program executed.
```

I step-debugged through the code in Eclipse and immediately after executing the

```
for lineno, line in enumerate(rh):
```

statement, `rh`, the handle for that opened file was closed. I had expected it to move onto the third line, printing out `This comes after!` to console and writing it out to `writetest_NoControlChars.txt` but neither events happened. Instead, execution jumped to `print "Program executed"`.
[Picture of Local Variable values in Debug Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfnAx.jpg)

Comment: You have to open this file in binary mode if you know it contains non-text data: `open(fn, 'rb')`

Comment: Changing `with open(fn, 'r') as rh:` to `with open(fn, 'rb') as rh:` like you suggested worked. Thanks (I'd be happy to accept your answer if you post it as such)!

Comment: I dug a little deeper and the documentation for [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) says opening a file in binary mode returns contents of the file as bytes without decoding. By default, `open()` operates in `'Text I/O'` mode, which is why it didn't work. I looked at the API for the [io module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase) but couldn't find anything that would explain why the file descriptor would be closed in text mode when those characters are encountered. Did I miss something? How can I dig deeper for an explanation?

Comment: Which operating system and Python version are you using? On my Mac with Python 2.7.11, your code above reports 'This comes after!' at the appropriate time.

Comment: `0x1A` is, on DOS and Windows systems, the End Of Text code `Ctrl-Z` for text mode I/O.

Comment: .. however, I can't find any mention of this in the source code of `_iobase` and `_textiobase`. So ultimately, this *may* piggy-back off the C standard library, which also does the same for Windows.

Comment: @usr2564301 That explains why if I wrote and read just `\x01` and not `\x01\x1A`, the program runs fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to open this file in binary mode if you know it contains non-text data: `open(fn, 'rb')`

Comment: What decides what is "non-text data"? Do you have a reference for that in the official documentation?

Comment: I guess any byte stream which cannot be assigned some known text encoding (utf-8, latin1, windows-1251, etc) should be considered binary. Opening file in binary mode turns off any automatic parsing/processing that happens for text files.